# Setting up a 2 node (ec2 ubuntu instances) Cassandra cluster

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, cqlsh

I'm new to Cassandra, and I'm trying to set up a simple 2 node cluster on two test ec2 ubuntu instances. but replication is not working, nodetool ring doesn't show both instances. What could I be doing wrong?
I'm using cassandra version 2.0.11.

here's what my config like on both machines:

```
listen_address: <private_ip>
rpc_address: <private_ip>
broadcast_address: <public_ip>
seeds: <private_ip_of_other_machine>
endpoint_snitch: Ec2Snitch
```

I have configured EC2 security group to allow all traffic on all ports between these instances. What am I doing wrong here? I can provide the cassandra logs if required.
Thank you.

EDIT: the error I'm getting currently is this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to gossip with any seeds
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.doShadowRound(Gossiper.java:1340)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.checkForEndpointCollision(StorageService.java:543)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareToJoin(StorageService.java:766)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:693)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:585)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:300)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:516)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:625)
ERROR 15:08:03 Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to gossip with any seeds
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.doShadowRound(Gossiper.java:1340) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.checkForEndpointCollision(StorageService.java:543) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareToJoin(StorageService.java:766) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:693) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:585) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:300) [apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:516) [apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:625) [apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
WARN  15:08:03 No local state or state is in silent shutdown, not announcing shutdown
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1st thing I see is that your seeds: list is wrong. Both nodes should have the same seeds: list. For a simple 2-node test setup, you only need 1 seed (pick either one). If the nodes are in the same AZ, you can use the private IP.

Comment: So what should be the seeds value in both machines? It currently hangs on "Handshaking version with /<private_ip>" before giving  "Unable to gossip with any seeds" exception.

Comment: you can use the private ip for node1. The seeds: list should be exactly the same on both nodes in the cassandra.yaml file. Start the seed node 1st and 2 minutes later start the other node. If they still won't talk, then stop cassandra on both nodes and delete the contents of the commitlog and data directories. This will effectively reset the database.

Comment: Okay thanks. I was using the binary from datastax website, I tried with a binary from cassandra.apache website and a newer version, and its now working. I'm using private IP for seeds value in node1, and private IP of node1 in seeds for node2. thanks again.